# Roman numerals in notes list in enotez

Tags: endnotes, roman-numerals, enotez

I want to use the package `enotez` because it allows you to click the endnote and link directly to the notes list. I need Roman numeral (lower case) numbers as superscripts for the endnotes. I can get this fine.

I can't, however, get the numerals in the list to b Roman numerals - they are still Arabic numerals. I've tried making a custom enotez-list as per the package instructions. This works for e.g. `\textsuperscript{#1}` but whatever I try I can't get a Roman numeral function to play with the `#1` macro. Any thoughts? MWE below and print out of what the working, wrong version looks like.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[counter-format=roman]{enotez} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}{
 notes-sep = \baselineskip ,
 format = \normalfont ,
 % number = \roman{#1} % broken attempt
 number = \enmark{#1}
}

\begin{document}

Hello life\endnote{This is an endnote.}

\printendnotes[custom]

\end{document}
```

[image: Working wrong code]

Comment: This was working with version 0.7c of the package. It looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for replying: tried your suggestion and it breaks. Error at the `\printendnotes` command: Missing number, treated as zero. []. Do you know what would cause that @clemens?

Comment: @mr_phd yes, it was wrong

Comment: @clemens I happen to have a `enotez.sty` file with `{enotez}{2014/02/04}{0.7c}` that produce OP's expected result with their MWE. Using the latest version on CTAN, I get the same result as OP. Looking at the source diff, there is _some_ difference in the treatment of the `counter_format` option.

Comment: @clemens On the latest CTAN version, lines 256 and 267, if I replace `\arabic {endnote}` with `\theendnote`, it produces the requested result. Which is the expected and correct result, I don't know.

Comment: I just sent an updated version (v0.9a) to CTAN. It should be available there in a few days and reach MiKTeX soon after. If you use TeX Live 2016 you can install it manually ([download](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/enotez/get/v0.9a.zip)) or wait until TL17 is published

Comment: @Sebastiano May I ask you to please be more careful with your edits? Always keep in mind, just because you don't understand an English phrase this does not necessarily mean it is wrong and should be changed.

Comment: @samcarter I had checked with google translate. That's why I made minor changes. I hope to be more careful.

Comment: @Sebastiano Shocking news, but google translate is not impeccable. If you are not sure (you and not google), don't do such minor edits.

Comment: http://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.1937.1493142634.4791.ctan-ann@ctan.org

Comment: Thanks for updating it. Does that mean in Tex Live (using MacTex) I will see an update for enotez at some point? Once I get it I'll test it out and reply accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer since v0.9a (2017-04-24) is: redefine `\theendnote`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enotez} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\renewcommand\theendnote{\roman{endnote}}

\begin{document}

Hello life\endnote{This is an endnote.}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]